# vim-go: Can't get autocompletion

Tags: vim, autocomplete, go

I'm trying to use [`vim-go`](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go), but I can't get autocompletion to work.

My go environment works well, I succesfully ran `:GoInstallBinaries`, and I can use any `:GoXXX` command without errors. But I can't get autocompletion to work.

- When I hit `<Ctrl-o>` after a dot, vim just switches in the status bar between `-- INSERTION --` and `-- (insertion) --` modes (what's the difference btw ?) and moves my cursor one character to the left.
- When I hit `<Ctrl-x>`, It just shows `-- mode ^X (^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y)` in the status bar.

Sometimes (rarely) after spamming `<Ctrl-o>` it shows the `vim-go` autocompletion tooltip ...

`vim-go` is the only plugin installed, using `pathogen`.

Comment: Did you try the combination `<Ctrl-x><Ctrl-o>`? That's how omni completion (which the plugin uses) is triggered. See `:h _i_CTRL-X_CTRL-O`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I didn't though I had to use both `<C-x>` AND THEN `<C-o>`. I though it was one or the other... What a complicated way. Thanks!

Comment: You can shorten that with a mapping; see my answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Omni completion* (which the Go plugin offers) is triggered via `<C-x><C-o>`, that is Ctrl + X followed by Ctrl-O. The prompt (`-- mode ^X (^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y)`) you've described hints at that.

If that is too cumbersome for you, you can define an *insert mode mapping* to shorten that; here's a (global) example to be put into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:inoremap <C-b> <C-x><C-o>
```

If you use GVIM, you can also use the IDE-like `<C-Space>` instead of the example `<C-g>` trigger.